# C++ Sockets WEB get information from priviliged sites

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

I have the following question. Request you to please provide your valuable inputs.

I know that C++ Berkley sockets could be used to fetch information from websites. The regular socket calls have to be used along with getaddrinfo method, to fetch the target machine information. A browser type GET request needs to be posted to server to fetch the required information.

How would the case be with secured websites? Like for example, i want to read data from a HTTPS site, where in the user needs to login to access content. The best example could be gmail.com. where in, in order to fetch all new mails, one has to logon.

Using sockets in C++, How to fetch content from sites like Gmail, by providing the required credentials in the GET request.

Any advice/suggestions/reference material ? Tried looking on Google, but no HELP?

Answer (score 1):

There's a few questions you're aiming at here.

First of all: To communicate with HTTP and HTTPS sites, do not use socket calls. Use a HTTP library, such as [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/); this will support both protocols, and will additionally support them better than your handcrafted code would.

Second: You cannot provide credentials to GMail (nor to most other sites!) in a GET request. Many popular web sites, GMail included, provide some sort of API for the express purpose of retrieving data from them. In the case of GMail, one of these protocols is [IMAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol). It is not based on HTTP, but it exists for the express purpose of managing an email account.